# How to use ghs_* token in github API?

Tags: github

I'm trying to build an integration between two repositories. For that I've decided to use Github Apps.

I was able to sign working JWT and use it to get an access token (`from https://api.github.com/app/installations/{{INST_ID}}/access_tokens`). It looks like this: `ghs_tVGHE4l5i4kjhasslirerno666222`.

Now I'm trying to use it to trigger an `dispatches` event for a project workflow with `on: workflow_dispatch:` trigger.

But I just can't find a way to put `ghs*` token to use.

Examples I saw say:

```
curl -X POST https://api.github.com/repos/{{user}}/{{repo}}/dispatches \
          -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.everest-preview+json' \
          -u ${{ ACCESS_TOKEN }} \
          --data '{...}'
```

But it does not work, `-u` option is for 'user', not for token.

How to use `ghs*` token with github api?

Comment: `-u <user>:<token>`?

Comment: Which username should I use? It's github App, there is no username. Initially I have private key, which I use to issue JWT, which I use to obtain 'access token'. None of it has any 'username' attached.

Comment: For those don't you need to put it in a header, as shown in https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/authenticating-with-github-apps#authenticating-as-an-installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to just use the `Token TOKEN` Authorization header:

```
-H 'Authorization: Token ghs_tVGHE4l5i4kjhasslirerno666222
```

You may also try using Basic authentication with the `x-token` username.  While that worked in the past, GitHub has disabled Basic authentication for the API, so that syntax may or may not function anymore.

Comment: oh, just replace `Bearer` (which is used for JWT) with `Token`? Thank you!